# Zend Framework: Push value in array

Tags: arrays, zend-framework

That is my array:

```
$rows = $this->fetchAll($a)->toArray();
```

How to push this exp. 'type' => 1 in all arrays in $rows?

Comment: can you be a little more clear in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either loop on each row of the result with a foreach and push the value on.  This is pretty basic array manipulation you can find examples of all over the place.

Or, skip the loop in code a graft the type = 1 into the SELECT statement.

```
$this->select()
     ->from(array(
         't' => 'fooTable'
     ), array(
         'type' => new Zend_Db_Expr($db->quote('1')), 
         'id'   => 't.id'
         'col1'   => 't.someothercolumn'
         'col2'   => 't.someothercolumn2'
     )
);
```